# Get list of all my facebook friends who studied in my College using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to figure out how to find how many of my friends and there basic information who has studied in the same school/university i have studies.

I am using `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/` tool of facebook.

I can i put condition in education field.

**If i want to get list of friends of friends then how can i get that?**

Comment: This is simply not possible.

Comment: @Tobi Can i do it by using FQL

Comment: No. This is not possible in FQL as well.

Comment: Thank You @Tobi, If i want this detail then how can i get... is there any other alternative,

Comment: You can parse the result on the application side, but it's afaik not possible to filter on education fields in FQL (which will be deprecated anyway on May 1st 2015.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52423/discussion-between-hitesh-modha-and-tobi)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using FQL and Facebook Graph API.